# Javascript requirejs, arcgis and dojo difference points

Tags: javascript, dojo, requirejs, arcgis

When I looking for javascript modular application I found [Requirejs](http://requirejs.org/) javascript library. This library makes js applications modular. I am working on [Arcgis Javascript API](https://developers.arcgis.com/en/javascript/). In this API you can use dojo and Requirejs features. For example:

```
require(["esri/map", "esri/layers/FeatureLayer"], function(Map, FeatureLayer) {
        map = new Map("mapDiv", {
          basemap: "streets",
          center: [-80.94, 33.646],
          zoom: 8,
          slider: false
        });
```

require() and define() methods are using in [Requirejs](http://requirejs.org/) library. But using in Arcgis API same time. And [Dojo](http://dojotoolkit.org/) API is using as well.

But when I add the scripts in same html file, Requirejs code not working.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://serverapi.arcgisonline.com/jsapi/arcgis/?v=3.2"></script>
<script data-main="js/main.js" src="js/require.js"></script>
```

I can not separate of the requirejs and other APIs. Is Arcgis API and Dojo is including Requirejs in itself?

Answer (score 3):

Dojo use the same AMD [syntax to load scripts](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dojo/require.html) but not the same syntax to [configure and bootstrapping](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/loader/amd.html#loader-amd). So if you use dojo you [need to switch](http://requirejs.org/docs/dojo.html) to the dojo syntax.

Answer (score 0):

requirejs library requires a **single entry point** to enforce modular loading. You cannot use other script tags before the line:

```
<script data-main="js/main.js" src="js/require.js"></script>
```